# Given a set, generate all permutations whose sums are less or equal to a given number

Tags: algorithms, permutations, subset-sum

I am looking for a way to generate every permutation (so order does matter) of a set of positive numbers whose sum is less than (or equal to) a given limit. I need to find the permutations themselves, and not only how many there are. For example, for the set {1, 2, 3} and the limit 6, I have to generate :

- Ø
- (1)
- (1, 2)
- (1, 2, 3)
- (1, 3)
- (1, 3, 2)
- (2)
- (2, 1)
- (2, 1, 3)
- (2, 3)
- (2, 3, 1)
- (3)
- (3, 1)
- (3, 1, 2)
- (3, 2)
- (3, 2, 1)

For the moment I have to following algorithm using dynamic programming (in Python), but I wondered if there was maybe a better, or more efficient, way to do it :

````python
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def equal(L, numbers):
    if L == 0:
        return [[]]
    
    results = []
    for n in numbers:
        if L >= n:
            temp = equal(L - n, numbers)
            results.extend(t + [n] for t in temp if n not in t)
    return results

def less(L, numbers):
    results = []
    for l in range(0, L + 1):
        results.extend(equal(l, numbers))

    return results
```
````

Comment: The word *permutation* has a specific meaning in mathematics, which is different from the one you use.

Comment: What is the complexity of your algorithm compared to the length of the output? If the same have the same order of growth, then your algorithm cannot be improved.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I guess you are right, but I did not know what word to use, as it is not really a subset (because order matters)... Maybe a subpermutation ?
And after a few tests, I can see the algorithm complexity is clearly exponential.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) gives some examples. The term *permutation* is only used to describe this kind of object in basic classes on combinatorics.